# How i can see pending notifications on Flutter local notifications?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification

I can schedule notification, but i want see pending notifications actives. It is possible?
Where flutter store time of notifications to show?

ex:

```
notifications.periodicallyShow(id, title, body, RepeatInterval.EveryMinute, _ongoing);
```

I want see where is 'RepeatInterval' value is stored

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the pending notifications using **pendingNotificationRequests**:

`var pendingNotificationRequests =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();`